# How to set REPORT_LOCALE in JaseprReports's report from PHP

Tags: java, php, jasper-reports

I'm using *JasperReports* Library with together with php and PHP/Java bridge and Tomcat 8 to be able to run a *JasperReports*'s report from php code.

Actually my working code is:

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once("http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");
if ( ! function_exists('run_report')) {
    function run_report($report_name = '') {
        //---------------------------------------------------------------
        // Esegue un report di Jasper Report
        // $report_name Ã¨ il nome del file .jwxml senza estensione
        //---------------------------------------------------------------
        try {
            $jasperxml = new Java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader");
            $jasperDesign = $jasperxml->load(realpath("./assets")."/".$report_name.".jrxml");
            $compileManager = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager");
            $report = $compileManager->compileReport($jasperDesign);
        } catch (JavaException $ex) {
            echo $ex;
        }
        $fillManager = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager");
        $params = new Java("java.util.HashMap");
        $params->put("id_record", 88);
        $class = new JavaClass("java.lang.Class");
        $class->forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        $driverManager = new JavaClass("java.sql.DriverManager");

    $locale = new Java("java.util.Locale");
        $conn = $driverManager->getConnection("jdbc:mysql://myhost:3306/mydb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "myuser", "mypassword");
        $jasperPrint = $fillManager->fillReport($report, $params, $conn);
        $exporter = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporter");
        $outputPath = "............outputfatt88.pdf";
        $exporter = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter");
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->JASPER_PRINT, $jasperPrint);
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, $outputPath);
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->REPORT_LOCALE, $locale);

        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=outputfatt88.pdf");
        $exporter->exportReport();
        readfile($outputPath);
        unlink($outputPath);
    }
```

I removed only some info about directories and database connection for obviously reason.

The above code is working but now I would need to set REPORT_LOCALE to set it to italian.

I made some search and I found this code in *Java*:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
metadata.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, locale);
```

I would need to convert it to php so that I can insert in my actual code, and need to change it to "italian" value.
I tried with no success in the following way:

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once("http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");
if ( ! function_exists('run_report')) {
    function run_report($report_name = '') {
        //---------------------------------------------------------------
        // Esegue un report di Jasper Report
        // $report_name Ã¨ il nome del file .jwxml senza estensione
        //---------------------------------------------------------------
        try {
            $jasperxml = new Java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader");
            $jasperDesign = $jasperxml->load(realpath("./assets")."/".$report_name.".jrxml");
            $compileManager = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager");
            $report = $compileManager->compileReport($jasperDesign);
        } catch (JavaException $ex) {
            echo $ex;
        }
        $fillManager = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager");
        $params = new Java("java.util.HashMap");
        $params->put("id_record", 88);
        $class = new JavaClass("java.lang.Class");
        $class->forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        $driverManager = new JavaClass("java.sql.DriverManager");

        $locale = new Java("java.util.Locale", "en", "US");
//db username and password
        $conn = $driverManager->getConnection("jdbc:mysql://myhost:3306/mydb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "myuser", "mypassword");
        $jasperPrint = $fillManager->fillReport($report, $params, $conn);
        $exporter = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporter");
        $outputPath = "/................./outputfatt88.pdf";
        $exporter = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter");
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->JASPER_PRINT, $jasperPrint);
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, $outputPath);
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->REPORT_LOCALE, $locale);

        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=outputfatt88.pdf");
        $exporter->exportReport();
        readfile($outputPath);
        unlink($outputPath);
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: `$locale = new Java("java.util.Locale", "en", "US");` - Did you try this code? You should use Italian locale (as I understand from your post) - "it_IT"

Comment: Yes; as you can see in my code I have `$locale = new Java("java.util.Locale", "en", "US");`, but when I add also this line `$exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->REPORT_LOCALE, $locale);` it breaks my code

Comment: `it breaks my code` - What does it mean? Did you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your locale corresponding to the target country:

```
$locale = new Java("java.util.Locale", "it", "IT");
```

Then add, as already done, the locale to the report:

```
$exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->REPORT_LOCALE, $locale);
```